# Does removing an unused element need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, dictionary, concurrency

Think that I have a `Map` or `List` with some obsolete values, which I'm sure any `Thread`s will not acquire.
Now I'm going to remove those values from map via a separate `Thread`. I repeat that I'm pretty sure that the value will not be acquired by any `Thread`s at the same time.
Now, do I need to make this operation synchronized? Please explain for both `List` and `Map`. Also, I use non-synchronized `HashMap` (Have no ideas about Thread safety of a `List`)
The reason that I'm asking this question is I know for example some hashing function will apply when each `Thread` adds or removes some value from a `HashMap`, or element shifting will be required in `ArrayList`s.

Comment: If you're not certain, I'd say better safe than sorry.

Comment: As long as only a single thread is updating the `List` or `Map`, then there is no need to synchronize the removal. As @childofsoong noted, if there is doubt, you may wish to use a conservative approach, but one needs to weigh the various trade-offs.

Comment: @KevinO I want to use a considerable number of  `HashMap`s in a SQL cache with many operations per second so performance matters for me here, and as concurrency reduces performance in most cases I need to be certain about costs.

Comment: If you are truly doing *caching*, then I highly recommend using a cache system such as `ehcache`. Anything you write for such operations is going to be more problematic. It can be done, but it is a lot of work. Seriously -- been there, done that.

Comment: @KevinO Thanks for your advice I stick that in mind. Also may I ask you do you know any SQL cache which can be integrated with `Quasar`?

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi, unfortunately, I have never worked with Quasar, so I am afraid I have no input. I would post that question. IMHO, your real question is how best to integrate caching with Quasar. Again, I would be very careful about attempting to integrate my own cache/cache expiration approach.